# Multiple error starting weblogic server

Tags: linux, oracle, oracle12c

Recently changed the password for our weblogic server by following these guides [1](https://blogs.oracle.com/imc/entry/change_password_in_weblogic) and [2](https://jvzoggel.com/2012/01/08/changing-weblogic-user-password/). I skipped the nodemanager password reset part for guide 2. But when I restarted the server encountered multiple issues  see below. Can you please advise on how to fix these errors.

```
Weblogic and Oracle Linux version
Weblogic 12c
Linux 3.10.0-229.el7.x86_64

A MultiException has 8 exceptions.  They are:
1. weblogic.security.SecurityInitializationException: Authentication denied: Boot identity not valid. The user name or password or both from the boot identity file (boot.properties) is not valid. The boot identity may have been changed since the boot identity file was created. Please edit and update the boot identity file with the proper values of username and password. The first time the updated boot identity file is used to start the server, these new values are encrypted.
2. java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: post construct on weblogic.security.SecurityService
3. java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: While attempting to resolve the dependencies of weblogic.jndi.internal.RemoteNamingService errors were found
4. java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: resolve on weblogic.jndi.internal.RemoteNamingService
5. java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: While attempting to resolve the dependencies of weblogic.rmi.cluster.RemoteBinderFactoryService errors were found
6. java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: resolve on weblogic.rmi.cluster.RemoteBinderFactoryService
7. java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: While attempting to resolve the dependencies of weblogic.cluster.ClusterServiceActivator errors were found
8. java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: resolve on weblogic.cluster.ClusterServiceActivator
```

Update

I wasn't able to pinpoint the exact error as to why it's giving me all these messages. But am almost 90% sure it's related when I modified boot.properties.
I was able to fix it by restarting the deleting some folders related to weblogic restart like ldap, sessions. Also deleted boot.properties and modified the username and password again which is similar to the original credentials I entered. Because I suspect that weblogic is not able to match the new boot.properties credentials with the configured credentials in weblogic.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the similar issue. Then followed below steps and it worked:

1. Added weblogic username and password in startWeblogic.[sh|cmd]
2. Clear the ldap and store directory under domain_home/servers//data
3. Cleared the tmp directory parallel to data directory (as above)
4. Restarted the managed server